# How many Bluetooth modules can work in one room?

Tags: bluetooth

I know that Bluetooth has a large band of frequencies but how much interference is there between them? How many of them can i have in a 25m2 small room without them interfering with each other under constant transmission load (each paired+load)?

Comment: You have 79 channels that devices randomly hop between.  So max at any tme slot would be 79, but others will wait for free slot.

Comment: so there is no bleed between the channels? That would be quite amazing. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...without them interfering with each other

**Two.**

Bluetooth devices change their communication frequency at about 1600 times per second. That is **on purpose** so that it is less of an issue when there is interference on some channels. Bluetooth is designed with the assumption that data packets will get lost and have to be re-transmitted.

When only two devices are communicating they are "in sync" regarding the channels that they use. Add a third device that is not "in sync" and that will transmit (to show its presence) at random channels. So collisions **will** happen. That's OK as it will not happen that often.

You ask for **no interference** and with Bluetooth that's not possible with more than two devices unless these would be "in sync" as well. But then not all devices would be able to communicate continuously, they would have to "take turns".

What you're asking (no interference) isn't how Bluetooth is designed. It is designed such that interference is expected and part of normal operation. That allows many devices to be used in a small space. More active devices will simply mean lower data transfer rates. But the system will continue to work which is an improvement compared to systems that are less immune to interference.

Comment: ok. Had no idea. Thanks. And how many can i expect to work (approximately) before they start reducing data transfer rates below  usable (around 400 KB/s)?

Comment: I dont think this is correct, at least not in all cases, considering BLE/BT4.0+.
The BLE device I worked on lets me choose one, two or all of three channels (37, 38, 39) which the device is going to use for advertising. And I'm sure there are other manufacturers which even let you exclude some channels for the connected-state. In this case, advertisements of one device will not interfere at all with other devices, if configured to use different channels exclusively.

Comment: And here you will find a website that states that channel-hopping at maximum of 1600 channels/sec is a feature of bluetooth classic. BLE devices implement a channel-selection algorithm. So for BLE the answer is: up to 37 channels (0 - 36) can be used for data transmission while 3 (37-39) are reserved for advertising. So a total of 37 simultaneous client-to-host connections should be possible without interference (in connected-state).
https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/examples/ble-channel-selection-algorithms.html

Comment: BLE mesh are recent developments that claim to support a mesh network of hundreds of bluetooth devices. Will it be reliable or just a disaster waiting to happen?

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Disaster: probably not. BLE relies on small and short packets (to save energy) so there's "room" for many devices. In a mesh it is possible to synchronize so the devices "take turns" and avoid collisions (not sure if BLE does that but I would expect it, I worked on BT but before BLE was a thing). So with more devices the speed of the network will simply go down but there's no reason that it would stop completely.

Comment: @bimpelrekkie - if we put wifi devices in the equation - assume smart TVs, laptops, mobiles streaming videos over wifi and at the same time BLE devices trying to do their job - what will be the impact. Will almost always busy wifi network, can the BLE network become close to unusable?

Comment: *can the BLE network become close to unusable?* I believe it should not as it is designed to work even under those conditions that you describe. Realize that not all devices are using the complete frequency band 100% all of the time. All devices transmit in bursts so there's always an opportunity for other devices. The 2.5 GHz band relies on devices "being nice" to one another. If that wasn't the case users would have issues and not buy such devices.